# Loop, split string containing '&'

Tags: batch-file

I asked this question very badly in another thread, and the answers I got didn't work since I asked it so badly. This time I'll try to get it right.

I want to go through all the files meeting a certain mask (*.txt) in a directory and, for each file, split the name into two strings.

Each file name has the format:

string1 by string2.txt

They're actually documents, and the file name is the document title and the author.

Both string1 and string2 can contain spaces; both string 1 and string 2 can contain the ampersand character ('&').

What I've got so far is this:

```
@echo off
echo.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.mobi) do (
call:split "%%f"
)
goto :EOF

:split
set "filename=%~1"
set "author=%filename:* by =%"
set "title=!filename: by %author%=!"
set "author=%author:.txt=%"
echo Filename: -%filename%-
echo Title: -%title%-
echo Author: -%author%-
echo.
```

which works fine except where there's an ampersand in either string. Then it all goes very pear-shaped.

If I could get rid of the subroutine and do it all in the for loop, that'd be good, too.

Comment: you can't `echo` a `&` without putting it in doublequotes. Can you live with an output of `"Asimov & Heinlein"` instead of `Asimov & Heinlein`? Or is it an option to replace it with a `+``?

Comment: Your write-up says files are *.txt, but your code looks for *.mobi. Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use delayed expansion `!var!` instead of `%var%`, and all content will be preserved, even poison characters like `&`. This would also allow you to get rid of the subroutine. But there is an easier way.

Use the `~n` modifier to get just the base name without extension.

Replace `" by "` with `":"`, a character that cannot appear in a file name. Then you can use a FOR /F loop to easily parse out the title and author. There is no need to assign variables for Title and Author - just use the FOR variables directly. Like delayed expansion, FOR variables also protect poison characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.mobi) do (
  set "file=%%~nF"
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in ("!file: by =:!") do (
    echo Filename: -%%F-
    echo Title: -%%A-
    echo Author: -%%B-
    echo(
  )
)
```

Or should it be

```
for %%F in (*.txt) do ...
```

If a title may contain the `!` character, then it will be corrupted when `%%A` is expanded because delayed expansion is enabled. The solution is to toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.mobi) do (
  set "file=%%~nF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in ("!file: by =:!") do (
    endlocal
    echo Filename: -%%F-
    echo Title: -%%A-
    echo Author: -%%B-
    echo(
  )
)
```

You still have one potential problem that I fear will be devilishly difficult to overcome - What if a title contains the word "by"? Off the top of my head I can think of a movie title, "North by Northwest". But I have to believe there are book titles as well. I wouldn't be shocked if there were an author that used a pseudonym with the word "by" in it.

The following modification will properly handle situations with one occurence of " by " in the title. It could be extended to support two, three, etc. within title. With recursion it could support N number of occurences. But if " by " can appear in the author, then I don't now how you could solve it.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.mobi) do (
  set "file=%%~nF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%A in ("!file: by =:!") do (
    endlocal
    echo Filename: -%%F-
    if "%%C" equ "" (
      echo Title: -%%A-
      echo Author: -%%B-
    ) else (
      echo Title: -%%A by %%B-
      echo Author: -%%C-
    )
    echo(
  )
)
```

Comment: ok, but as I see it, it isn't possible to put it into variables and use them without using doublequotes. Am I right, or is there a trick to do so? (`set` works, but `echo` them seems to be a big problem to me because the parser will catch it)

Comment: @Stephan No, you can always use delayed expansion for _any_ content. `echo !works!` instead of `echo %works%`, as delayed expansion is the last phase of the batch parser

Comment: @jeb: you are right, it works. Hm - If found my failure: I tried with `%` otuside the block "as usual". That makes my answer obsolete. Thank you, jeb and dbenham

Comment: That answer is great, dbenham - thanks a lot. The one remaining problem is, as you suspected, the possibility of the word "by" in the title. Does case sensitivity help here? I can make it so that all words in the title and author are capitalized; so that if there's a "by" in the title or the author, it will actually be " By ", rather than " by ".

Comment: @user1773179 - Changing case will not help because batch search and replace is case insensitive. See my updated answer for a variation that supports one occurence of " by " in title.

Comment: dbenham - thanks, but that version won't work for me. Here's the output I get (for various inputs):

Filename: -Title by One by Author One.mobi-
Title: -Title by One-
Author: -%C-
Filename: -Title Two by Author Two.mobi-
Title: -Title Two by Author Two-
Author: -%C-

Comment: @user1773179 - You must not have copied the code properly - It works fine for me. I suspect your tokens definition is wrong. It should be `tokens=1,2*`, but I think you have `tokens=1,2`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't echo a `&` without putting it in doublequotes. If you can you live with an output of `"Asimov & Heinlein"` instead of `Asimov & Heinlein`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.mobi) do (call :doit "%%i")
exit /b

:doit
set string=%1
set string=%string:&=§%
set string=%string: by =.%
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("%string%") do (
 set str1=%%a
 set str2=%%b
 set str1="!str1:§=&!"
 set str2="!str2:§=&!"
 echo( --!str1!--!str2!--
)
goto :eof
```

If it is an option to replace it with a `+`:

```
@echo off
set string=
for %%i in (*.mobi) do ( call :doit "%%i" )
exit /b

:doit
set string=%1
set string=%string:&=+%
set string=%string: by =.%
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in (%string%) do (
   echo --%%a--%%b--
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you've said - where you say "if you can live with an output of "Asimov & Heinlein".... it looks like the two alternatives you give are the same, both including the '&'. In any case, when I run the first solution you give, it fails with a problem about the character '┬º'. And both of the solutions only act on the last file in the directory.

Comment: @user1773179 - The difference is one form has quotes, the other doesn't. But there is no need for quotes if you use delayed expansion.

Comment: @dbenham: would you mind, showing me how? Somehow I can't find a way do to it without quotes (first option)

Comment: @user1773179: sorry, my fault. Edited to process all matching files.